# Find rows matching a value and not matching another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I did a search on the board before I posted this but I could not find anything that covers the same scenario, although I believe it is here buried somewhere I could not see it...

I'm learning SQL and trying to build a query that returns the column **IndexNr**
when **IndexNr** row contains the **ID = x** but **IndexNr** does not contain any row with **ID = y**

I not looking for any particular **IndexNr**... I want all of them that has **ID = x** but the same **IndexNr** that returns a match for **ID = x** cannot be considered a match if it also has **ID = y** in one of the rows from **Pos** column... Does that makes sense?

```
IndexNr     Pos    ID
----------- ------ -----------
100001      0      -30140
100001      1      -28877
100001      2      -31659
100001      3      -28282
100003      0      -30262
100003      1      -30261
100003      2      -30260
```

So I tried this, but of course my limited SQL skills are keeping me from seeing the further clauses I'm missing to achieve this outcome...

```
SELECT [ToolNr] FROM [WTData].[dbo].[ToolParts] 
WHERE PartID = -30140 AND PartID <> -28877
ORDER BY [ToolNr]
```

From the query above, the **IndexNr 100001** should not be returned as a match...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any relationship between `ID` in your sample data and explanation and `PartID` in your query? When you wrote `PartID = -30140 AND PartID <> -28877` did you ponder which number might pass muster?

Comment: There's no relationship... x can be > y and vice versa... Tks for asking though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look for `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery, if I understood you right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.indexnr
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.id = <your x>
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.indexnr = t1.indexnr
                                          AND t2.id = <your y>);
```

If `(indexnr, id)` is unique, you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

An alternative could be aggregation. Assuming that your *x* < your *y*:

```
SELECT indexnr
       FROM elbat
       WHERE id IN (<your x>, <your y>)
       GROUP BY indexnr
       HAVING max(id) = min(id)
              AND max(id) = <your x>;
```

It first gets only records where the `id` is either your *x* or your *y*. Then these are grouped by `indexnr`. Now, for an `indexnr`, if all of those previously filtered rows contain either only *y* or only *x* in `id`, `max(id)` must be equal to `min(id)`. Since we want only *x*, we can check if `max(id)` (or `min(id)`) is *x*.

Comment: Thank you... that did the trick... Good to learn a bit more about subqueries...

Comment: The logic for your final query is more generally written more like:  `having max(id) = min(id) and max(id) = <your y>`.  Your version would fail if y > x and both appear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, you're right, I mixed up `min()` and `max()` and/or *x* and *y*. And your way is easier to understand and to handle. I edited the answer, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @sticky bit There's no relationship... x can be > y and vice versa... Tks for asking though.